# Is it possible to play an animation in both directions with a single @keyframes rule?

Tags: css, animation, transition

I would like to use a single `@keyframes` rule to animate an element from one state to another and then to get back to the original state when I do an action (with the same animation). I saw that using `animation-direction: reverse;` is a way to play the animation in reverse. However, when I try to use it, the transitions on my element disappear. If I set a new `@keyframes` with the reversed state it works fine.

What is the point of `animation-direction` in this case? I am misunderstanding something?

Is there a way to play an animation in both directions with a single `@keyframes` rule without loosing the transitions? I can't use `transition`, I need `animation`.

Here is a example to play with (hover the squares):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: fade 0.6s ease-in-out forwards;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

#box-1:hover {
  animation: fade 0.6s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

#box-2:hover {
  animation: fadeReverse 0.6s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% { background: red; }
  100% { background: blue; }
}

@keyframes fadeReverse {
  0% { background: blue; }
  100% { background: red; }
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1">:(</div>
<div id="box-2">:)</div>
```

Comment: now u want to animate an element from one state to another and then to get back to the original state  I'm right ?

Comment: @AmareshSM Yes, and I would like to use a single `@keyframes` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you apply the same animation to the element on hover as the animation that is on the default state of the element.

So the element already had that animation with the default direction but then you apply it again with the reverse. But it won't work. I don't really know why this happens. But applying the same animation on an element twice, won't work. So you need 2 different keyframes.

You can use a `reverse` animation or duplicate the existing one and use it with `direction: reverse`

Read more here 
[restart animation](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)

[more info here](http://dabblet.com/gist/1656494)

[another article here](https://justmarkup.com/articles/2015-01-26-restart-css-animation-using-css-to-trigger-a-reflow/)

If you REALLY want to use just 1 animation this can be solved with javascript by removing and adding an 'animate-me' class . But it still wouldn't be ideal

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: fade 0.6s ease-in-out forwards;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

#box-1:hover {
   animation: fade2 0.6s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

#box-2:hover {
  animation: fadeReverse 0.6s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% { background: red; }
  100% { background: blue; }
}
@keyframes fade2 {
  0% { background: red; }
  100% { background: blue; }
}

@keyframes fadeReverse {
  0% { background: blue; }
  100% { background: red; }
}
```

```html
<div id="box-1">:(</div>
<div id="box-2">:)</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's all the info I needed. :)

Comment: THere are a bunch of  semi-solutions in the second link but my advice is to use 2 different animations or to 'remove/add' a class from javaScript and animate that. Glad i could help. Cheers ! :D

Comment: I think I will go for the 2 animations because I don't think the JavaScript solution can work if I want a transition in both directions.